# Tab bar icon and title not showing with Storyboard References

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios9, storyboard-reference

I have the following storyboard with a segue to a storyboard reference:

[image]

The problem is that when I run the app, it doesn't show the icon or the title:

[image]

These are the item settings:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I am also having same issue, you find any solution?

Comment: Somebody just posted an answer bellow. I'm not on this project anymore so please let me know if it works and I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's how to get the tab to show properly:

1. Put the first UIViewController that will be embedded in the tab in
   the *same storyboard* as the UITabViewController.
   [image]
2. Ctrl + Drag from the tab bar controller to the content view
   controller to make the connection as per usual. This will
   automatically add the UITabBarItem to the bottom of the content view
   controller.
   [image]
3. Select the content view controller.
4. Click the Editor menu and choose Refactor to Storyboard...
   [image]

The UITabBarController tab will now point to the new storyboard reference...
[image]
... and the content view controller preserves the UITabBarItem from the tab bar relationship. It will appear normally in the app now.
[image]

Comment: Is there any way we can make the relationship by ourself?

Answer (score 18):

You can modify image/title of the tab bar item in the initial view controller of the storyboard you are referring to. You just need to add a 'tab bar item' to the initial view controller and change its properties (title/image) accordingly.

1. Outline view of the root view controller in the referred storyboard

[image: document outline of referred to storyboard]

2. The modified tab bar item in the view controller

[image: initial view controller with modified tab bar item]

Note: the change will not be reflected on the tab bar in the main storyboard; you only see it in the referred storyboard and at runtime.

Comment: Why does the tab bar disappear in the storyboard?  Is it an Xcode bug?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that it is a different file (Storyboard) and Xcode doesn't implement it (reading the entry view controller from a referenced story-board). So more a feature lacking than an actual bug I would think.

Comment: This solution is the quickest one. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that in the target view controller, you don't have a UITabBarItem in the views hierarchy. The TabBarItem is related to the storyboard reference, but should be related to the View Controller.

Looks like a "bug" in Xcode...

To resolve this you can do the following:

- Just create the segues from the UITabBarController to the Storyboard references.
- You may configure the Tab Bar Items in the storyboard references, they don't do much more other than showing the tabs in the tab bar on the Storyboard, which is nice for development purposes.

If you now run the app, you will indeed notice that the tabs are missing. 
To get the tabs to display in the running app as well, do this:

- Go to the viewcontroller the storyboard reference is referencing to
- Add a Tab Bar Item into this View Controller by dragging it from the Object Library into the View Controller
- You will now see a tab bar with one single tab in the view controller
- Configure the tab bar item to show the correct title and icon

Now run the app and you will now see your tabs.

[image: In interface builder, find the Tab Bar item in the Object Library]

[image: Drag the Tab Bar item into your the destination view controller by following the storyboard reference]

Comment: This solved my problem. Even though I did not need to add bar items to other ViewControllers that are also displayed in the same UITabBarController. I only needed to do this with one of the view controllers for it to display. Weird stuff

Comment: You actually gave the same answer as @Driess https://stackoverflow.com/users/6216669/dries

Comment: this solved the issue for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

I tried adding another tab bar, then added tab bar item, selected and image for it BUT Non of above seemed to work with my case ..
it was like this :
[image: Other VC tabs were showing tabBar icons properly but one that i refactored was missing its icon]

Then i compared it with VC that were working properly with TabBar icons..
[image]

later i found that my navigation items and tab bar items were not together :

[image: The Tab bar item was inside with Navigation Bar.... i dragged the tabBar item to HomeVC and placed with NavigationBar item]

Now its working :):)

[image]

Comment: This was what worked for me. Setting up these tab bar items is a little tedious because of the story board reference

Answer (score 4):

After struggling with this problem for a few days I found this solution. 
Double click the storyboard link, which will open the referenced storyboard. In the scene navigator, you can edit the bar item with a custom title and icon. Works in xCode 9.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRiOL.png)

[Scene Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWJFe.png)

Comment: Adding the bar item by directly opening the storyboard that is referenced/has the initial VC will not work. Follow steps above such as if you want to open the initial VC of the tab, open it by clicking the storyboard reference

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue and neither of the above answers worked in my case. I solved by setting my tab bar image in the *image* bar item section inside the storyboard's reference like shown in the attached image:

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add a Tab Bar Item in the "child" view controller:

[image]

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

I made following in the storyboard and made class for each `UINavigationController`
and made following code in each `UINavigationController` class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let someController = StoryboardManager.surveyStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SomeController") as! SomeController
        viewControllers = [someController]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it in different way. My fourth tab was not showing. I just programmatically placed image on its place. You need to set its X,Y coordinates accordingly.

```
    let imageName = "video"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - 80, y:  view.frame.height-70, width: 50, height: 50)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
```

[image]